# anti aliasing issue with the width of SVG element path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using the D3 to draw a line chart. However I found the lines with lower slope(flat) is thinner than the lines with higher slope(steep), I guess this is because of anti aliasing is working?
The width is a fixed number, and the zooming are controlled by transform and scale.
When the line is horizontal (almost parallel to x axis), then it become impossible to see in chrome and firefox, and in safari, it is still discoverable.

I tried using every combination of different option in shape-rendering and vector-effect. Doesn't seem to change the situation.

The constant width of that path no matter how steep it is.

Here is the overview:
[image]
Zoom a little bit in chrome:
[image]
Zoom in further more, then you can see some line are missing.
[image]
However safari can still show the line, although the width is still changing as slope changes
[image]

The same drawing codes for a different datasets which shows the exact problem, inconsistent width.
[image]

Any suggestion or link would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please post a working example [mcve]. We can't really debug your code by looking at screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for viewing this question and answer. I just found the solution for my own problem.
What I am trying to do here is building a zoomable line chart.
The problem is the scale transform also squash the width of horizontal (or nearly horizontal) lines.
So the solution is, vector-effect set to non-scaling-stroke. And don't change the width of the path while zooming.
And that's it.